# NTFS partition - can't resize

Tags: partitioning, lubuntu, gparted, ntfs

I've got a WD My Passport 1TB drive formatted as NTFS. It had 600GB free and so I wanted to create a 100GB ext4 partition and install Linux on the 100GB. So I opened GParted and tried to resize. It would not allow me to resize.[image: GParted's Dialog]

How do I resize? I don't have a Windows PC to run chkdsk on, so I need linux tools only.

I do have a modern.ie vm though, if that's of any help.

Comment: Are you able to see the contents of that NTFS partition?

Comment: Yes , can read and write to that partition.

Answer (score 0):

Simple fix.

Open a terminal, and run:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ntfs-3g
sudo reboot
sudo ntfsfix /dev/sdb3 #Replace accordingly
```

Comment: this didn't work, ntfsfix threw up no errors and ntfs-3g was already installed